# UISlider not getting called when it ends sliding

Tags: ios, iphone, uislider

I am using UISlider in my project, but I want to fire event when user end dragging the Slider.

I have following code.

```
    [progressBar addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(sideProgressBarValueChanged)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void) sideProgressBarValueChanged
{
    NSLog(@"Changing values");
    // Some action
}
```

I set this setContinuous to false.

```
[progressBar setContinuous:false];
```

but sometimes its not getting call.

I am confused that what else should I use to perform accurate results.
Can anybody suggest something?

Comment: why [progressBar setContinuous:false];? What happen if [progressBar setContinuous:true];?

Comment: I want to execute my code only user stop sliding. So with [progressBar setContinuous:false]; it will fire only at last, but sometimes it wont, and that is the issue.

Comment: sideProgressBarValueChanged just fire when UISlide changes value. How about Touch Up Inside event? It will fire after user touch up.

Comment: Sometimes its not getting call. Don't know how this happening.

Comment: Did you try to Touch Up Outside, and more ..? You can add more than 1 event touch ... in a UISlide